# Apache mod_rewrite explanation

Tags: regex, apache, symfony, mod-rewrite

Can anyone explain how will this mod_rewrite regular expression work?

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Symfony/web/app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I enter `http://localhost/hello/testingonly`, what will it be redirected to?

EDIT:

I am currently trying to use Symfony Framework and trying out the online tutorials.
`http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/hello/testingonly` actually displays a page that says "Hello $name" and $name in this case refers to "testingonly".

So if you visit this page `http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/hello/matthew`, the page will say "Hi mathew".

The next thing I wanted to do was to remove Symfony/web/app_dev.php from the URL and I copied and paste the rewrite rule above and it just worked well.

What I wanted to know is how does it interpret which one is name parameter.

If I were to visit `http://localhost/hello/mathew`, and based on the rewrite rule, it should just be `http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php` and the parameter should be lost. But how come it managed to display "Hello mathew" ?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific in what exactly you don't understand? mod_rewrite is quite complex and allows to define various rewrite rules and conditions for different purposes. Above example uses a regexp to rewrite all requests in used apache context (dir/host...) to ```app_dev.php```. See [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: @Matthias, sorry for not being specific. I will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

This rule redirect **everything** to `/Symfony/web/app_dev.php`.

```
                ^(.*)$ match everything (start, any char 0~n times, end)
               /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Symfony/web/app_dev.php [QSA,L]
                                              /  /
           [QSA] keep GET parameters in the URL / 
                                               /
   [L] mean "if match, does not read next rules"
```

As you don't have he `[R=301]` flag, this redirection is transparent.

So :

- `http://localhost/hello/testingonly` redirect to : 
  `http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php`, but URL remains the same.
- `http://localhost/hello/testingonly?foo=bar` redirect to : 
  `http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php?foo=bar`, but URL remains the same.

Comment: Hi Zessx, thanks for your response. I edited my question above and based on your answer if http://localhost/hello/testingonly redirects to http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php, then wouldn't my parameter be lost? How did the page managed to display "Hello testingonly"?